# public page visualforce don't work

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I created a public site for my visualforce. On my page, I'm don't using Apex class, just Visualforce.

My page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Curso__c" recordSetVar="cursos">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Plataforma de Cursos do Mario">
        <apex:form >
            <h1> Bem vindo, escolha um curso e bons estudos! </h1>
            <br/><br/>
            <apex:pageBlock title="Cursos Disponíveis:">
                <apex:repeat value="{!cursos}" var="curso">
                    <h1>Nome: {!curso.Name}</h1>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}">
                        Data do curso:<apex:param value="{!curso.CreatedDate}" /> 
                    </apex:outputText>
                    <p></p>
                    <apex:image value="{!curso.Link_da_Imagem_do_Curso__c}" width="350px" height="200px" />
                    <p>{!curso.Descri_o_do_Curso__c}</p>
                    <br/>
                    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='{!curso.Link_do_Curso__c}'">ACESSAR CURSO</button>
                    <hr/>
                    <br/><br/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

In Developer Console -> preview, my page works and she lists my Courses (list of Curso__c) !

[image]

But on my public site, the list doesn't work...

[image]

This is a link for my public site: [https://cursosmario-developer-edition.na156.force.com/](http://This%20is%20a%20link%20for%20my%20public%20site:%20https://cursosmario-developer-edition.na156.force.com/%20%20%20He%20doesn%27t%20list%20my%20Courses...%20Why??%20Please,%20help%20me)

He doesn't list my Courses... Why?? Please, help me

Comment: Sites use a guest user for public access.  Have you checked the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_guest_profile_best_practices.htm&type=5) for guest user permissions?

Comment: yes, and in Sharing detail from Guest User, in table, the column "User Access" have value "Full Access"

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe the specific permissions you have granted, like object, sharing, Visualforce page, etc